# MySQL sum of column group by question

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the results of a select that I am joining on that I need to get a slightly complex sum of 
a column from.

I need the sum of result grouped on id PLUS the sum of result of any row where parent_id = id.

The data from the join:

```
cat_id   parent_id   name    result
------   ---------   -----   ------
1        2           name1   7 
1        2           name1   1
2        4           name2   2
```

For example from the above I need a result like:

```
cat_id   name    sum(result)
------   -----   -----------
1        name1   8
2        name2   10
```

Any ideas much appreciated

Comment: I would use UNION of 2 queries.May not be the smarted solution, but simple to understand (not sure what your row count is)

Comment: Thanks Manny I'll look into it - the row count from the join is about 1,000

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(result)
FROM (SELECT cat_id as id, name, result  FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.parent_id as id, t2.name, t1.result 
FROM test as t1 
LEFT JOIN test as t2 ON t2.cat_id = t1.parent_id
) as a 
GROUP BY id,name ORDER BY id
```